# about triggers in sql server 2008 and 2007

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need triggers window how can i find it in the sql server 2008 and 2007? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcut for the Template Explorer is : Ctrl + Alt + t in that you can get template for trigger of sql

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio, connect to your database and expand the node [YourDatabase]->Programmability->Triggers. If you right-click that folder, Management Studio will give you options to generate script templates for both create, modify and remove triggers.

Comment: I have right clicked that folder but nothing will happen! 
[mydatabase]-->Programmability-->database triggers  and when I right click on this folder it will show "refresh"